# Best Join Strategy/Indexes for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

What is the best join strategy/indexes for this query:

```
SELECT 
    kwk.*, an.AuftragDatum, an.AbgabeDatum, an.BezahltDatum, an.AuftragStatus 
FROM 
    KundenWerbenKunden kwk
INNER JOIN 
    Auftrag an ON an.AuftragNummer = kwk.AuftragNummer
WHERE 
    kwk.Deleted = 0
```

Table `KundenWerbenKunden` has 103950 rows with 103646 `Deleted = 0` ones.

Table `Auftrag` has 3826552 rows.

In my real query I make some more joins:

```
INNER JOIN 
    Filiale fn WITH (NOLOCK) ON an.FilialeID = fn.FilialeID 
INNER JOIN 
    Kunde kn ON an.KundeID = kn.KundeID 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT DISTINCT KSKNr 
     FROM KdZuordnung 
     WHERE KundeID = kn.KundeID) zn 
LEFT JOIN 
    Anrede ann WITH (NOLOCK) ON kn.Anrede = ann.Anrede 
INNER JOIN 
    AuftragArt aa WITH (NOLOCK) ON an.AuftragArtID = aa.AuftragArtID 
INNER JOIN 
    AuftragGrund ag WITH (NOLOCK) ON an.AuftragGrundID = ag.AuftragGrundID 
INNER JOIN 
    AuftragType at WITH (NOLOCK) ON an.AuftragTypeID = at.AuftragTypeID
```

Comment: Any primary keys? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Just the fastes i can reoder the table. I use sql-server

Comment: A filtered index on `kundenwerbenkunden` using `where geloescht = 0` is probably going to help if the majority of rows in that table has `geloescht = 1`

Comment: Can you write me an code example?

Comment: Also replace `*` with the actual columns needed, because this is quite important for choosing the right indexing

Comment: Did it. See it above.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM KundenWerbenKunden kwk INNER JOIN
     Auftrag an
     ON an.AuftragNummer = kwk.AuftragNummer
WHERE kwk.Geloescht = 0;
```

And not knowing anything about the distribution of `Geloescht`, I would first try indexes on `KundenWerbenKunden(Geloescht, AuftragNummer)` and `Auftrag(AuftragNummer)`.

Comment: "geloescht" means "deleted" - so it's likely to contain only `0` and `1`

Comment: With some includes? Without includes nonclustered i got 4 seconds.